# On change update image position json with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm stuck on my project and i'm putting my hopes on you guys, to tell me how to move further.
Currently my code allows to drag and drop images left or right. This should define image positions. Now i don't know how to make a function which would update image position in my json. Let me show you my code and i will explain further

This is the response i get from server for my images.

```
[{"id_image":0,"thumbImage":"http://lorempixel.com/242/242/?52704","image":"http://lorempixel.com/1024/768/?37489","position":0},
{"id_image":1,"thumbImage":"http://lorempixel.com/242/242/?20352","image":"http://lorempixel.com/1024/768/?89352","position":1},
{"id_image":2,"thumbImage":"http://lorempixel.com/242/242/?27924","image":"http://lorempixel.com/1024/768/?45708","position":2},
{"id_image":3,"thumbImage":"http://lorempixel.com/242/242/?45140","image":"http://lorempixel.com/1024/768/?88511","position":3},
{"id_image":4,"thumbImage":"http://lorempixel.com/242/242/?10979","image":"http://lorempixel.com/1024/768/?98296","position":4}]
```

and this is my HTML which shows and allows dragging and dropping images left or right

```
<form>
  {{images}}
  <div class="row clearfix">
      <div ui:sortable ng:model="images" id="main" style="overflow:auto;">
         <div  ng:repeat="i in images track by $index" id="editProductImages">
            <figure class="d_xs_inline_b">
                <div>
                  <img src="{{i.thumbImage}}" alt="{{product[0].name}}">
                </div>
            </figure>
         </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

I also added a little bit of JQuery to make make this working since whole template is already written in JQuery

```
//Sort product images
$(function() {
    $('#editProductImages').sortable({
        connectWith: '#main',
        scroll : false
    });
});
```

And this is how my project currently looks like
[image: Sort images]

And this are my controller functions now

```
productsFactory.getProduct(alias).then(function(data){
    //Fetch product data
    $scope.product = data;
    //Fetch images
    $scope.images = data[0].images;
})
    //Sort images function, how??
    $scope.updateImagePosition = function(){

    }
```

The problem is i don't wan't from users to press any submit buttons what so ever. I wan't this to happen instantaneously when ever user moves any of image left or right. I hope you guys can help me. If you need any additional information, please let me know and i will provide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `update` attribute of the `sortable`. I have shown how it works here. You can edit it to change the JSON you have. And as in the below code, this will work in angular too!

```js
var app = angular.module("myapp", []);
app.controller("c", function($scope) {
  $("#sortable1").sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
    change: function(event, ui) {
      $(this).attr('data-previndex', ui.item.index());
    },
    update: function(event, ui) {
      var start_pos = $(this).attr('data-previndex');
      var index = ui.item.index() + 1;
      var text = ui.item.text();

      $(this).removeAttr('data-previndex');
      $("#msg").append(text + " moved from " + start_pos + " to " + index + "</br>");
    }
  }).disableSelection();
});
```

```css
#sortable1,
#sortable2 {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  width: 142px;
  min-height: 20px;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 0 0 0;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
#sortable1 li,
#sortable2 li {
  margin: 0 5px 5px 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">


<body ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="c">

  <ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
  </ul>
  <p id="msg"></p>



</body>
```

Comment: Hi! Thx for effort, but is see one problem here. The code doesn't use any angular functions. I have to make this working with angular, so when ever user changes position of images, json will be updated and also data will be saved in to the database.

Comment: This code works in angular too. Just to show it, now I have edited and added it in angular controller.

Comment: ooo nice. Sorry didn't know. As you can see i'm beginner :). ok i will try it out.

Comment: Okay. And if it works, please mark this question as correct. Thanks

Comment: Of course. Who first one answers,  is first potential candidate for marking questions as correct.

Comment: Ok some how it's now working jet, but i got your point and i see what did you do, so i'm marking this answer as correct since now i know how to proceed. Thank you